# DRF - How to correctly Update a Foreing Key

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble updating my User object since my request send a "customer id" (example: 12) but my serializer y waiting for a dict

To be more clear, here is the message I get: ***Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.***

What I'm trying to acomplish is to update my customer field from my user which is a ForeingKey

here is my viewset.py:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        customer = BankCustomer.objects.filter(id=request.data.get('customer'))
        serializer = UserSerializer(customer, data=request.data)
    except BankCustomer.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(None, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

user serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = BankCustomerSerializer()
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'lastname', 'type', 'customer', 'is_blocked')


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.customer = validated_data.get("customer", instance.customer)
        instance.email = validated_data.get("title", instance.email)
        instance.name = validated_data.get("name", instance.name)
        instance.lastname = validated_data.get("lastname", instance.lastname)

        return instance
```

customer serializer:

```
class BankCustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, source='customer_r', queryset=User.objects.all(), default='')

    class Meta:
        model = BankCustomer
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'ruc', 'address', 'phone', 'users')
```

Comment: Didn't see your model code. But it is because your `customer` is declared as a `BankCustomerSerializer` so that it expected a dict but not a primary key. But it will be more cleared if you provided your model code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to send just the customer id field for the update, but you want to get the whole Customer instance in the response.

One way to accomplish this is by using the serializers RelatedField like this:

```
class CustomerListingField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return Customer.objects.get(id=data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.all()
```

Then, in UserSerializer replace the:

```
customer = BankCustomerSerializer()
```

with this:

```
customer = CustomerListingField()
```